# API Console data corrupted. Cannot recreate Client ID for a particular package and production key

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-api-console

API Console data seems to be corrupted for my account. I cannot recreate the Client ID for package **com.clc.mmm.free** and my production key.

The error I am getting is "This client ID is globally unique and is already in use", **although no Client ID exist for this package in any of my active or deleted API Console projects**.

Please note that I could delete and recreate Client IDs for other packages and keys with no problem.   The issue is related with package com.clc.mmm.free.

This issue prevent me to publish my new version of the app which includes singn-in with Google+.
I'll really appreciate if an engineer from API Console team can look into this. Thank you.

(Sorry to re-post this issue, but I believe this better describes the problem  as it cannot be easily reproduced probably...)

Comment: Is this still repeatable now?  There have been some recent bugfixes go live.

Comment: Hi Tim, I just checked now and the issue is still there. I can provide the SSH1 fingerprint or any other information if needed beside the package name, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: It is working now! I contacted Naveen A. over the weekend and he just emailed me that he managed to get the magic done on the backend. Thanks Naveen and Tim!

Comment: Calin can you tell me how you contacted someone in Google? I am also having the same problem.. it worked for the debug key but not for the published one.. its horrible I cannot use it after the all settings

Comment: Hi Tim, Can someone do the magic against my account as I am having this issue since yesterday and nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This didn't work! I silly made a typo. Can someone provide me some assistance ASAP, as I need to post an update on the PlayStore soon!

For those who are still having this problem and have not got in contact with Google Developers. I had this idea where I thought maybe if I attempt to trigger some sort of update then it might clean up the database. And it seemed to have worked. What I did was, I edit the branding information of the OAuth by adding a '/' to the end of by website url. And then tried to add the production key and it seemed to have worked!

If it doesn't work, try editing all your branding information across projects that you have previously linked before, so it cleans up all the different targets. If this doesn't work then I have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

Even if you delete the projects from the Game Services section in the Google Play Developer Console the project will remain in some database.

To "really" delete the projects you should try to delete the projects in the Google Api Console here:

https://code.google.com/apis/console

This worked for me.